# Using ngView directive without hash in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS Part:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/main', {templateUrl: 'sub/main.tpl', controller: MainCtrl}).
    when('/users', {templateUrl: 'sub/users.tpl', controller: UserCtrl}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'});
}]);
```

and my index.html

```
<a href="#/main">Main</a> | <a href="#/users">Display Users</a>
<div ng-view></div>
```

It works great but I am having problem with hashes.

When I try to use an anchor i.e:

```
<a href="#test">test</a>
```

when I click on this anchor it is calling the main page.

Is it possible to get rid of the hashes when we use ng-view?

Comment: what are you expecting to happen? Question is not clear. It sounds like you may need a directive for the link but need more details

Answer (score 0):

Ah, because AngularJS reroutes your urls.
Try using ng-href,

```
<a ng-href="#test">test</a>
```

Edit: You can try changing the id of the anchor to the angular url..